# Concatenating multiple files python

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge multiple files into one file using python, I've tried several methods but they all result in the final file missing out on some lines. The size of the file can vary a lot, so I'd prefer using something which does not load the whole file into memory.

My knowledge on this is a bit limited but I read that it's probably due to the writing buffering aka, the file is not immediately written, the information is instead kept momentarily in memory and later written to the file.

I've tried multiple ways to solve this: using shutil.copyfileobj, classical python's read/write , adding a tag to the end of the file, checking the tail of both files, using file.flush followed by os.fsync, and finally, adding a few seconds of time.sleep. Everything fails, could anyone advise on an infallible way to merge files?
Some approaches seem to work fine on my local PC, but when tried on an another system (HPC) the error occurs, so this is kinda hard to replicate.

these are all the approaches I tried so far:

```
#support functions
def tail(file_path):
    last_line = None
    with open(file_path) as file:
        line=file.readline()
        while line:
            last_line=str(line)
            line=file.readline()
    return last_line


def wait_for_flush(output_file,tail_in):
    c = 0
    while not file_exists(output_file):
        sleep(5)
        c += 1
        if c > 100: raise BrokenConcatenation(output_file)
    tail_out = tail(output_file)
    while tail_out != tail_in:
        while not tail_out:
            sleep(2)
            tail_out = tail(output_file)
            c += 1
            if c > 100: raise BrokenConcatenation(output_file)
        tail_out = tail(output_file)
        c += 1
        sleep(2)
        if c > 100: raise BrokenConcatenation(output_file)

def merge_two_files(file1,file2):
    with open(file1, 'a+') as f1:
        with open(file2) as f2:
            line=f2.readline()
            while line:
                f1.write(line)
                line=f2.readline()
        #forcing disk write
        f1.flush()
        os.fsync(f1)

#main functions

def concat_files(output_file,list_file_paths,stdout_file=None,add_tag=False):
    print('Concatenating files into ',output_file,flush=True,file=stdout_file)
    print(output_file)
    list_files=list(list_file_paths)
    while len(list_files)>1:
        file1=list_files.pop(0)
        file2=list_files.pop(0)
        merge_two_files(file1,file2)
        sleep(1)
        os.remove(file2)
        list_files.append(file1)
    final_file=list_files.pop()
    move_file(final_file,output_file)


def concat_files(output_file,list_file_paths,stdout_file=None,add_tag=False):
    print('Concatenating files into ',output_file,flush=True,file=stdout_file)
    with open(output_file, 'wb',buffering=0) as wfd:
        for f in list_file_paths:
            with open(f,'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
                #forcing disk write
                wfd.flush()
                os.fsync(wfd)
                sleep(2)

def concat_files(output_file,list_file_paths,stdout_file=None,add_tag=False):
    print('Concatenating files into ',output_file,flush=True,file=stdout_file)
    with open(output_file, 'w+') as wfd:
        for f in list_file_paths:
            with open(f) as fd:
                line = fd.readline()
                while line:
                    wfd.write(line)
                    line = fd.readline()
            if add_tag:
                tail_in='#'+f+'\n'
                wfd.write(tail_in)
            else: tail_in=tail(f)
            # forcing disk write
            wfd.flush()
            os.fsync(wfd)
            wait_for_flush(output_file,tail_in)


#resets file whenever we open file, doesnt work
def concat_files(output_file,list_file_paths,stdout_file=None):
    print('Concatenating files into ',output_file,flush=True,file=stdout_file)
    for f in list_file_paths:
        with open(output_file, 'wb') as wfd:
            with open(f,'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
                #forcing disk write
                wfd.flush()
                os.fsync(wfd)


def concat_files(output_file,list_file_paths,stdout_file=None):
    print('Concatenating files into ',output_file,flush=True,file=stdout_file)
    with open(output_file, 'w+') as outfile:
        for f in list_file_paths:
            with open(f) as infile:
                line=infile.readline()
                while line:
                    outfile.write(line)
                    line=infile.readline()
            #forcing disk write
            outfile.flush()
            os.fsync(outfile)


def concat_files(output_file,list_file_paths,stdout_file=None):
    print('Concatenating files into ',output_file,flush=True,file=stdout_file)
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as wfd:
        for f in list_file_paths:
            with open(f,'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
                #forcing disk write
                wfd.flush()
                os.fsync(wfd)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read large files into memory, I would say this should just work:

```py
def concat_files(output_file, list_file_paths):
    print('Concatenating files into', output_file)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as wfd:
        for f in list_file_paths:
            print(f, '...')
            with open(f) as fd:
                for line in fd:
                    wfd.write(line)
                wfd.write(f'eof - {f}\n')  # mod to indicate end of this file
    print('Done.')
```

This should create the `output_file` as a new file and read each file from `list_file_paths`, a line at a time, writing to the new file.

**Update:** see *mod to indicate end of this file*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this addresses the buffering issue.

Comment: Which buffering issue is that?

Comment: "I'm trying to merge multiple files into one file using python, I've tried several methods but they all result in the final file missing out on some lines. "
The problem is that when you try to write, the file is not immediately written, which leads to  missing content when you try to write again to the same file.
Please check the code that I provided too :)

Comment: I'm sure that's not a thing. The OS is in charge of actually getting bits onto the platter, so when you say 'the file is not immediately written' that's because of the cache. So you can't know that has happened, because if you try to read the file, you get the contents of the cache which should make you believe that the data came from the disk.

Comment: So, what could be the explanation for the missing data in the merged file? I have no clue, and have been trying to fix this for days now.

Comment: So, does my solution suffer from these aberrations?

Comment: I tried something similar in the past and it did, but I'll try it again and let you know.

Comment: same issue, notice how the first line is properly formatted, the last line is cut short by the top of the next concatenated file:
first line:

Q1RLU9               -            418 NOG.ENOG410ZP15.meta_raw -            672   4.2e-10   35.2   0.0   1   1   5.5e-12   5.7e-10   34.8   0.0    31   230    86   278    80   303 0.80 -

second line:
Q8GY82               -            351 NOG.ENOG410ZP15.meta_raw - #                                                                                --- full sequence --- -------------- this domain -------------   hmm coord   ali coord   env coord

Comment: Are the files that you are reading themselves being updated by another process?

Comment: no, the files are already written. the only file being written is the output_file

Comment: And what about now with the `mod to indicate end of this file`?

Comment: I already tried it with the mod too. and then implemented the wait_for_flush which would check the tail of each file.